# Collect systeminfo of different systems automatically

Tags: system-info

We have a number of systems of which we want to collect the system information using a tool like systeminfo. We are thinking about starting it together with the system so whenever a hardware component was changed and the system is started systeminfo updates the information for this system on a central system. Does that make sense to collect the information using systeminfo and sending it to a server or is there a better option (e.g. collecting system information from a remote computer)?

Answer (score 1):

While **SystemInfo** also supports connecting to remote systems, I suggest using something more flexible and powerful like [**Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) instead. Here are some useful links to get you started:

- [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Example: Getting WMI Data from a Remote Computer (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer by Using Windows PowerShell (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309377%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Powershell PC Info Script (WMI)](http://www.hackyeah.com/2010/08/powershell-pc-info-script-wmi/)
- [WMI Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186146%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572)
- [Collecting Remote System Information With WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8804/Collecting-Remote-System-Information-With-WMI)

  [image: 1]
- [Retrieving hardware information with WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6360/Retrieving-hardware-information-with-WMI)

  [image: 2]